# Xp_CmdShell Powershell Script No Valid Module Found

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to run a PS1 file in T-SQL using XP_CMDSHELL, like so:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -command "C:\Users\sleven\Documents\DimAcctImport.ps1"'
```

The powershell script is as follows:

```
import-module dbatools
Import-DbaCsv -SqlInstance 'MSSQL' -Database 'Test' -Table 'Account' -Path "R:\Data\Account.csv" -Delimiter ',' -Quote '"' -KeepNulls -NoProgress
```

This script uses the cmdlet `Import-DbaCSV` of module `DbaTools` to import the CSV to the target table.

Here is the error I receive in SSMS:

```
import-module : The specified module 'dbatools' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 
directory.
At C:\Users\sleven\Documents\DimAcctImport.ps1:1 char:1
+ import-module dbatools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (dbatools:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

The module is installed and runs as expected if I copy the PowerShell script and run it in PS ISE.

I'm using SQL Developer Edition on the same PC as I'm using to run the sp - my local PC.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Adding output from get-module and $PSVersionTable

```bsh
PS> (Get-Module -ListAvailable dbatools).Path:
C:\Users\sleven\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\0.9.834\dbatools.psd1

PS> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145                                                                                          
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145                                                                                         
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Can you add the line `(get-module -ListAvailable dbatools).path` list the output? Also, what version are you using (`$PSVersionTable`)? Does it work if you import module using its path (`Import-Module C:\Path\to\module.psm1`)?

Comment: Added output results as an edit to original post @robdy

Comment: Ok, change first line of script to `Import-Module 'C:\Users\sleven\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\0.9.834\dbatools.psd1'` and see if it works.

Comment: That did work! I had to move the file because SQL Server doesn't have permission to R:\, so I moved the file to C:\ and it worked perfectly. @robdy

Comment: Perfect. Let me quickly write the answer then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Import-Module` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1) tells PowerShell to look for cmdlet only in certain folders. You can check these folders by checking environment variable `PSModulePath` (splitting added for better visibility):

```bsh
$env:PSModulePath -split ';'
```

In that case, when running PowerShell by `xp_cmdshell`, that folder is not included in `PSModulePath` (might happen as well if you use different account as your module is currently in your profile folder). Now you have two options:

1. Reference the module using its path, not name. You can get path using `(get-module -ListAvailable dbatools).path`:

```bsh
# Replace the path with the path you found with Get-Module
Import-Module 'C:\path\to\module\dbatools.psd1
```

2. Modify your `$env:PSModulePath`. As that topic is more broader, let me give you [the link to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path). Remember that you should set that variable for the user running `xp_cmdshell`. [As RThomas mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081853/9902555), by default it's not your user account. See linked answer for explanation on that topic.

**NOTE** (credits go to [@David Browne - Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) from his comments):

> If you're going to set the environment variable, it should be a system environment variable, as you wouldn't want this process to break if you change the SQL Server service account. And remember, setting a system environment variable requires a reboot for services to see the change.

Comment: If you're going to set the environment variable, it should be a system environment variable, as you wouldn't want this process to break if you change the SQL Server service account.  And remember, setting a system environment variable requires a reboot for services to see the change.

Comment: Thanks David, I added your important remark to my answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's likely an account issue.  Keep in mind that running xp_cmdshell by default runs everything as the service account behind the SQL Server instance.  So you'll want to verify what account this is.

If it's a built in system account this can cause strange behavior when it comes to rights.

If it's a windows or a domain account then you'll want to test externally to SQL Server by running the PS file not as yourself but as the same account SQL Server uses as a service account.  You can do this easily by opening the cmd shell with shift/right click and specifying the other account.

Your other option is to set up a proxy account for the xp_cmdshell call to use.  [Instructions on how to do this can be found in Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Sounds like you came to that same conclusion with robdy in the comment section.  I'll leave the answer simply for the link to running xp_cmdshell under a proxy account.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't even consider that xp_cmdshell runs under the service account. Makes sense though. I just tried to install another module and I needed to add -Scope CurrentUser to get around access restrictions.